# Update query in google app engine data store (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jdo

How to use the update query in google app engine while using with gwt. I'm trying to make a chat application where apart from submitting and deleting the previous messages, the administrator can edit out the portions of existing messages.

For editing the existing messages update query is needed and I could not find anything like update query in data store.

How can we update the existing data?

Comment: How is the usage of GWT relevant ?
Did I understand the question in my answer below ? If not can we steer each other in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej3.html
You can do a get modify your data then a make persistent and then commit.

### See the updateContact() method in the attached code.

The main caveat is doing this across entities - Note: Data storage in the DataStore is different than a relational DB.

```
package gaej.example.contact.server;

import gaej.example.contact.client.Contact;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public class ContactJdoDAO implements ContactDAO {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper
            .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory getPersistenceManagerFactory() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory()
                .getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(contact);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Contact> listContacts() {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory()
                .getPersistenceManager();
        String query = "select from " + Contact.class.getName();
        return (List<Contact>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
    }

    public void removeContact(Contact contact) {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory()
                .getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.currentTransaction().begin();

            // We don't have a reference to the selected Product.
            // So we have to look it up first,
            contact = pm.getObjectById(Contact.class, contact.getId());
            pm.deletePersistent(contact);

            pm.currentTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    public void updateContact(Contact contact) {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory()
                .getPersistenceManager();
        String name = contact.getName();
        String phone = contact.getPhone();
        String email = contact.getEmail();

        try {
            pm.currentTransaction().begin();
            // We don't have a reference to the selected Product.
            // So we have to look it up first,
            contact = pm.getObjectById(Contact.class, contact.getId());
            contact.setName(name);
            contact.setPhone(phone);
            contact.setEmail(email);
            pm.makePersistent(contact);
            pm.currentTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `makePersistent()` on an entity that has been retrieved or previously inserted will update the entity in the datastore.  See [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Updating_an_Object).

Comment: what is pm.refresh(Object o) good for then? i thought this is the "update" function in jdo in app engine. (at least it works)