# how to update a field value of a data store in google app engine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I had created a Login (Kind) in the data store. Inside the login, I created two fields username and passsword. When the user changes the password I want to update the field value inside the datastore. but when I used this code,

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity passwordchange = new Entity("Login");
passwordchange.setProperty("password", "admin@123");
datastore.put(passwordchange);
```

It creates a new row and inserts the password "admin@123" instead of updating the new password in same row.

Can anyone suggest me how to update the data of a field.

Comment: You need to use the same Entity object for each row. And this isn't a table or relationship database, so don't think of it as one. That will just dig you into holes.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Updating_an_Object) and also see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679759/update-query-in-google-app-engine-data-store-java)

Comment: so i have to write a seperate JDO class for updating data. is that what you people are saying am i right?

Comment: you have to get the same entity you originally created and update the contents of that, rather then creating a new one.

Comment: fine can you say how to get same entity. Am not having idea how to get it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to update an entity, you have two options:

A. Retrieve this entity from the Datastore by its id. Update property. Put it back into the Datastore.

```
try {
    loginEntity = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("login", id));
    loginEntity.setProperty("password", "admin@123");
    datastore.put(loginEntity);
} catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
// This should never happen
}
```

B. Create a new entity using the same id. Add all properties. Put in a Datastore - it will override the old entity.

```
Entity loginEntity = new Entity("login", id);
loginEntity.setProperty("password", "admin@123");
datastore.put(loginEntity);
```

In both examples id is the id of your entity that you want to change.

**I hope you do not store passwords as strings.**

Comment: Thank you so much Andrei you are genius... i got exactly what i want.

Comment: Is the same thing doable with the cloud libraries (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) ? I can't find the `setProperty` method

Comment: In these libraries it's simply "set", e.g. 'Entity task = Entity.newBuilder(taskKey)
        .set("description", "Buy milk")
        .build();'